# ¿Como importar varios modulos en python?

Tags: python, python-import, modulos

Necesito importar varios modulos a mi proyecto y es necesario importar todos de una carpeta porque solamente asi me funcionaria mi aplicacion al convertirla a .exe

Verán, lo que quiero es importar todos los modulos de una carpeta de python , por ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

```py
import reportlab.graphics.barcode
```

o

```py
from reportlab.graphics.barcode.common import *
from reportlab.graphics.barcode.code39 import *
from reportlab.graphics.barcode.code93 import *
from reportlab.graphics.barcode.code128 import *
from reportlab.graphics.barcode.usps import *
```

o

```py
from reportlab.graphics.barcode import code39, code128, code93
from reportlab.graphics.barcode import eanbc, qr, usps
```

Comment: Checa [answer], una explicación que de contexto a tu código siempre será bien vista!